# 2015 Mazda CX-5 High Beams

Tags: mazda, headlight, cx5

The high beams on my 2015 Mazda CX-5 stopped working for no apparent reason. I've already changed the bulbs, the fuse, the relay, and the switch on the column, to no avail? I'm now at a loss, other than a wiring issue. I'm looking for suggestions and advice. TIA.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!